# Email validation compliant with RFC 2821

Tags: php, regex

I searched for a while now and only found ready-to-use-solutions for other RFC standards. Also I think that the PHP build in function filter_var is also not for me because (according to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)) the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL-constant only makes it check for RFC 822 adresses.

I only found this JAVA regex:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])
```

But before trying to translate this mosnter into PHP with my amateurish Java skills I rather would like to ask here in the forum ..

Up to now I use the following (incomplete) regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9-\!\\\\\$\&\*\=\^\`\|\~\#\%\'\+\/\?\_\{\}]{2,}[@][a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

What would be the appropriate regex to check email addresses according to **RFC 2821**?

Comment: send verification code to that email and verify by them is only way which works really

Comment: As what @NullPoiиteя said, send the verification code through email. The regex won't stop the users from providing an email address which although valid, can be completely bogus.

Comment: I agree NullPoiиteя comment and before to send e-mail, you can check is there exists a MX entry for the domain because if it not exists, the e-mail  sending will certainly fail. this can been tested with the function `getmxrr` http://php.net/getmxrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  NullPoiиteя comment:

> send verification code to that email and verify by them is only way which works really

Answer (score 0):

you can use [rfc822.php](https://github.com/iamcal/rfc822/blob/master/rfc822.php) to validate email

```
require_once "ref822.php"
if(is_valid_email_address("email..")){
    //valid
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this standard compatible with RFC 2821? I havn't found any information about that during my research ..

Comment: well it is 822/2822/5322 but not 2821 yea, sorry